# Is it a good idea to use HttpSessionId to manage user session?

Tags: spring, session

I'm building my webapp with spring and hibernate.

Now I'm facing the problem of managing the user session.

I'm using HttpSessionId and the idea is to save is on a database when the user login, so that I'd have userId and sessionId mapped in my database.

The first question is: is that correct? I mean, I know it works, but, is it a good practise?

On the other hand, as I see it, I coundn't provide any "remember me" option, because HttpSessionId may change... How would I manage it?

Comment: Why do you store the session ID in the database? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to provide user-authentication. I'm new in it, I'm just exploring options. Shouldn't it be stored in database?

Comment: No. You check the user name and password, and if correct, you store the user ID in the session, so that, for each subsequent request, you know it comes from that user ID, by looking in the session. Why would you need to store the session ID in database?

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll store user id in session.

Comment: Maybe yuo may consider to use spring security in order to build a secure user context for your webapplication